# Linux vnet0 network interface does not exist

Tags: linux, networking

I have added a network interface in the "/etc/network/interfaces" file :

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
#iface eth0 inet static
#   address 192.168.19.82
#   gateway 192.168.19.154


# VirtualBox NAT bridge
#auto vnet0
iface vnet0 inet static
 address 172.16.0.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 bridge_ports none
 bridge_maxwait 0
 bridge_fd 1
```

The network manager is active, I tried activating the `managed` flag and disabling it but still, restarting the network service does not create the `vnet0` interface.
What could be blocking the creation of this interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, the NetworkManager service has absolutely nothing to do with Debian's `interfaces` file. Interfaces listed there are only managed by the **ifupdown** tools (also known as the `networking` service).

(NetworkManager can read the "ifcfg" files on Fedora/CentOS, but everywhere else it uses its *own* configuration storage at `/etc/NetworkManager`.)

1. If you want to use `/etc/network/interfaces`, run **`ifup vnet0`** to activate the configuration. As far as NetworkManager is concerned, that interface should remain unmanaged.
2. On the other hand, if you want to use NetworkManager, *remove* vnet0 from `interfaces` and use NM's own tools for this (e.g. nm-connection-editor). Though unfortunately I don't think NM supports creating *empty* bridges (you could put a dummy0 interface there though).

Comment: `ifup vnet0` worked perfectly, is there a way to make it permanent?

Comment: The `auto vnet0` option you have commented out indicates that this interface should be brought up with `ifup -a`, which usually happens on boot (unless you are running systemd, and systemd decided it didn't need to do that). See `man interfaces`. So uncommenting it should to the trick.